# volttron BACnet grab_multiple_configs.py

Tags: python, volttron

I am trying to auto discover BACnet devices in VOLTTRON on a LAN with [grab multiple configs](https://volttron.readthedocs.io/en/latest/driver-framework/bacnet/bacnet-auto-configuration.html#grab-multiple-configs-options).

This message below is from the linux terminal when I am trying run `proxy_grab_bacnet_config.py` where my args or something is incorrect:

`usage: grab_multiple_configs.py [-h] [--use-proxy] [--proxy-id PROXY_ID] [--out-directory OUT_DIRECTORY] [--ini INI] csv_file`

This is my BACnet proxy ID: `d80cd203-696b-4219-a4f2-b8bb56b7d116`

When I run this from terminal:
python grab_multiple_configs.py --out-directory ~/Desktop/volttron/scripts/bacnet/configs/ --use-proxy --proxy-id d80cd203-696b-4219-a4f2-b8bb56b7d116 multie.csv

I get the usage error, is it because my args aren't in the correct order?

```
usage: grab_multiple_configs.py [-h] [--use-proxy] [--proxy-id PROXY_ID] [--out-directory OUT_DIRECTORY] [--ini INI] csv_file
grab_multiple_configs.py: error: argument csv_file: can't open 'multie.csv': [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'multie.csv'
```

***EDIT***
Snip of `vctl status`:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The proxy-id should be the vip identity of the proxy you are using.  not the uuid.  I am guessing that having the - in the uuid is probably why this is an issue.  Try " the arguments and see if you get the same error.  Though it won't work unless the proxy id is in fact the vip identity.

Comment: Any chance you could comment on the snip I posted in the EDIT of the `vctl status`? I still dont get it. Same error if I use `python grab_multiple_configs.py --out-directory ~/Desktop/volttron/scripts/bacnet/configs/ --use-proxy --proxy-id platform.bacnet_proxy multie.csv`